# clustering element in list based on a metric

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a list of dictionaries which are keywords and its vector distances, and I am trying to apply clustering techniques to group them

```
# data = [{"key": "str1", "weight": float value}, ...]
# distances = [item['weight'] for item in data]
distances = [0.004906579754566209, 0.008361678408906337, 0.010228429212122636, 0.013671005756098031, 0.013671005756098031, 0.013713535105272179]

mean_distances_differences = mean([j-i for i, j in zip(distances[:-1], distances[1:])])
```

I calculated the mean of differences between two consecutive elements in the list. if the distance between two elements is less than mean i want to cluster them, so the result will be

```
[[0.004906579754566209], [0.008361678408906337], [0.010228429212122636], [0.013671005756098031, 0.013671005756098031, 0.013713535105272179]]
```

Here I think I cannot use knn because i dont know how many clusters can occur. so I have tried like this

```
distances = [item['weight'] for item in data]
mean_distances_differences = mean([j-i for i, j in zip(distances[:-1], distances[1:])])
distances_new = distances
required_list = []
while distances_new:
    temp = []
    if len(distances_new) == 1:
        temp = distances_new
        required_list.append(temp)
        break
    else:
        for i,j in zip(distances_new[:-1], distances_new[1:]):
            if j-1 < mean_distances_differences:
                temp.append(i)
            else:
                break
        distances_new = [_i for _i in distances_new if _i not in temp]
    required_list.append(temp)
```

But I am getting the answer

```
[[0.004906579754566209, 0.008361678408906337, 0.010228429212122636, 0.013671005756098031], [0.013713535105272179]]
```

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff to calculate the distances, I took the absolute because I am not sure if the distance would be sorted:

```
import numpy as np
distance_diff = abs(np.diff(distances))
```

If you do cumsum of whether the distance is greater than some value, it will group consecutive elements that are smaller than the threshold together:

```
np.cumsum(distance_diff > abs(np.mean(distance_diff)))]

array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

So all remains is to provide a starting group 0:

```
np.hstack([0,np.cumsum(distance_diff > abs(np.mean(distance_diff)))])

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```